# CListCtrl resets horizontal scroll position

Tags: winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I'm having an issue with an MFC CListCtrl in report mode where whenever

- the horizontal scroll position is not at the beginning
- and the Shift key is pressed

as soon as an item is selected via a left-button mouse click, the horizontal scroll state reverts back to the beginning.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and was able to reproduce this with an example application. A simple dialog-based MFC application with a CListCtrl, two columns and two items shows this behavior under Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Is there a way to prevent this, so that the CListCtrl keeps the scroll position?

**Update**

I've added a MCVE below, where I used the New-Project Wizard of VS 2015 to create a dialog-based MFC application named ListScroll where I statically link MFC.

I've also noticed that there doesn't need to be already one item selected. Even selecting one item with the Shift key pressed shows this on my systems.

[image: Running example program showing the scroll issue]

**ListScroll.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
   #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"

class CListScrollApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
   CListScrollApp();

public:
   virtual BOOL InitInstance();
   virtual int ExitInstance();

   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CListScrollApp theApp;
```

**ListScroll.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ListScroll.h"
#include "ListScrollDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListScrollApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CListScrollApp::CListScrollApp() {}

CListScrollApp theApp;

BOOL CListScrollApp::InitInstance() {
   CWinApp::InitInstance();

   CListScrollDlg dlg;
   m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
   INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
   if (nResponse == IDOK) {
      // Do nothing
   } else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL) {
      // Do nothing
   } else if (nResponse == -1) {
      TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: dialog creation failed, so application is terminating unexpectedly.\n");
   }

   return FALSE;
}

int CListScrollApp::ExitInstance() {
   return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

**ListScrollDlg.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"

class CListScrollDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
   CListScrollDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);

#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
   enum { IDD = IDD_LISTSCROLL_DIALOG };
#endif

protected:
   virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
   virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
   CListCtrl m_wndList;
};
```

**ListScrollDlg.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ListScroll.h"
#include "ListScrollDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

CListScrollDlg::CListScrollDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
   : CDialog(IDD_LISTSCROLL_DIALOG, pParent)
{}

void CListScrollDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) {
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_wndList);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListScrollDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CListScrollDlg::OnInitDialog() {
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   m_wndList.InsertColumn(1, _T("Test 1"), 0, 200);
   m_wndList.InsertColumn(1, _T("Test 2"), 0, 800);

   m_wndList.InsertItem(1, _T("Item 1"), 0);
   m_wndList.InsertItem(1, _T("Item 2"), 0);

   return TRUE;
}
```

**ListScroll.rc**

```
IDD_LISTSCROLL_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "ListScroll"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,209,179,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14
    CTEXT           "TODO: Place dialog controls here.",IDC_STATIC,10,96,300,8
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,7,7,306,162
END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941173/clistctrl-how-to-maintain-horizontal-scroll-position

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade The topic you've linked to discusses a different issue. I'm not repopulating the list here, the scroll position reverts just by Shift+Clicking when already one item is selected.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which styles are used for the list control?

Comment: @zett42 It's LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP

Comment: Still can't reproduce (Win 10, VS2013). Can later try to reproduce with VS2015 but propably doesn't matter. [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @zett42 I've added an MCVE and an example video exemplifying the issue.

Comment: I copy-pasted your MCVE but still not reproducible. This time VS2017 on Win10 build 15063.332. My VS2015 installation appears to be broken, but I doubt it would make a difference as the list control is not an MFC control.

Comment: consider removing the horizontal scroll: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314263/how-to-disable-the-horizonal-scrollbar-of-a-clistctrl-in-mfc

Comment: I'm still looking into this and haven't found any solution yet. In the meantime, I've also tested with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 Version 1709 Build 16299.19 (Fall Creators Update) and can still reproduce the scroll jump.